# ¿la función eval() de php reconoce funciones?

Tags: php

Tengo este problema: estoy evaluando un código php con la función eval() de php, pero dentro del código hago una llamada a una función y al parecer no la reconoce. El código viene siendo como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$codigo = "$var = 'Hola '; echo $var . get_name();";
$codigo.= "function get_name(){echo 'Pepe';}";
eval($codigo);
```

Pero el navegador me devuelve como resultado que no encuentra la función llamada get_name();
¿Alguien sabe por qué puede estar saliendo ese error?

Comment: Pareciera que si, pero no entiendo bien:

[Mira Aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167961/calling-user-defined-functions-in-php-eval)

[Y Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php)

Comment: Es porque la funcion get_name() la esta buscando en tu archivo de codigo php, no en la variable $codigo

Comment: Esto es más un problema con el mal uso de las comillas que con el `eval`

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer declaraciones de variables se debe usar el caracter "\" antes del nombre de la variable, y las funciones a utilizar es mejor declararlas antes de hacer la llamada, de la siguiente manera:

```
$codigo = "function get_name(){return 'Pepe';}";
$codigo .= "\$var = 'Hola ';  echo \$var .  get_name();";
eval($codigo);
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la asignacion $var ( debe estar fuera de la variable $codigo) Proba este codigo

```
    $var = 'Hola ';
    $codigo = "  echo '$var' .  get_name();";
    $codigo .= "function get_name(){return 'Pepe';}";
    eval($codigo);
```

Comment: Probé  ese código y funcionó, lo que sucede es que yo ejecuto la función eval() dentro de un método, y por ello todo el código que quiero evaluar debería estar dentro de una variable, de lo contrario toda variable que vaya a usar tendría que declararla global. Estuve probando a declarar la función antes de hacer la llamada y funcionó. Saludos

Comment: Excelente. Ya tienes la solución. Y veo que remplazaste el echo por el return en tu función. Como el codigo que te pase. El echo hacia que la impresión de las palabras sea inversa.